# FreeRADIUS - What does "obsolete" modules mean?

Tags: rest, module, freeradius

Most of the modules on the official FreeRADIUS website are marked as "Obsolete". Specifically, I'm interested in the rml_rest module, it appeared recently, but is already outdated. Does this mean that its support has been discontinued and problems may arise in new versions, or how is this to be understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the web server generation, which has now been fixed. `rlm_rest` is definitely not obsolete.